# problem or bug with simplepaginate livewire

Tags: laravel-livewire

I want to use simplepaginate from livewire but I have a problem.

I'll explain, I have a delete button on each row of the table, when I go to the last page with paginate I have only one row, if I click on the delete button it works normally but my table becomes empty and the message of 'no record in table is displayed' yet the database still contains data.

[image: last page of my table]

[image: page error for me because i now i have auther data in my data base]

Comment: do you stay at the same page after deleting?

Answer (score 0):

You should go back to page one after each deletion.

To do so you can use the `$this->resetPage();` that is added by the `Livewire\WithPagination` trait